# What is the role of tag preferences

Tags: support, tagging

In the right pane there is link to set tag preferences. What is the role of this feature and how exacly it will alter interaction with this forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an [old blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/expressing-your-tag-preferences/) about this. The basics haven't changed much; the technical implementation, somewhat.